# Which bibliography package should I use for my thesis in LuaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, luatex

I'm about to start writing a (B.Sc.) thesis. As there are some rather peculiar layout requirements (such as using Times New Roman) at my university chair I would like to use LuaTeX in order to be able to adapt to those requirements if necessary.

Similarly I might need to adapt my bibliography to fit those requirements. Is there a flexible bibliography package that is known to work well with LuaTeX?

Comment: Use `biblatex` and `biber` (the latter is a replacement for traditional `BibTeX` the program).  One exception to this piece of advice is if there is a specific style you need to use and there already exists a `.bst` file for it: then use it and `BibTeX` (and `natbib` if necessary).

Comment: A more important question is what bibliography style you want to use. If there is a predefined one available for 'traditional' BibTeX then I'd be tempted to go with this: using LuaTeX _per se_ shouldn't make a difference. If however you've got to start from scratch or want more complex things (humanities-style references, multiple bibliographies) then `biblatex` is going to work better long-term.

Comment: I've closed as 'opinion based' but might also be 'too broad' or even 'unclear': certainly as it stands not going to get answered.